# Is there a shortcut of += if not zero in {} in ruby

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

Is there any shortcut (syntaxtic sugar) function in ruby to do this?

```
# x[5] += 3 that zeroes first if x[5] does not exists

x = {}
x.key? 5 ? x[5] = 3 : x[5] += 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out for size:

```
x = Hash.new(0)
x[5] += 3
puts x[5] => 3

x[5] += 3
puts x[5] => 6
```

Using Hash.new(a_value) will make the hash return that value when no key exists: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Hash/new/class

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that a gotcha is if you do something like x = Hash.new([]) it will return the same array for each missing value.

Answer (score 3):

there indeed is a shorthand notation for initializing if not initialized.

```
x = {}
x[5] ||= 0 # x[5] is 0
x[5] += 3  # x[5] is 3
x[5] ||= 0 # x[5] is 3
x[5] += 3  # x[5] is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's only integer you can do this:

```
x[5] = x[5].to_i + 3
```

you can set a default value:

```
x=Hash.new(0)
```

You may want to do this which is a more global solution

```
x[5] = (x[5] || 0) + 3
```